# Is there a way that i can find the same row of a randomised table in an sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, sqlite, replit

I'm doing a project for my computer science course and I've created a table in a database with 3 columns. I need to randomise the order of the table then set 2 of the columns as one variable, and the other column as a different variable. However, I can't find a way to randomise the table in the same way for both variables (the 2 variables will be from different rows of the table)

I've already tried using the OFFSET command within the select statement however the programme keeps displaying the error that the 'column doesn't exist' even when i referenced no column.

```
new_db=sqlite3.connect("database.db")
c=new_db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT artist, first_letters FROM songs ORDER BY RANDOM()LIMIT 1")
row=c.fetchone()
c.execute("SELECT title FROM songs ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
row2=c.fetchone()
print(row)
print(row2)
new_db.commit()
new_db.close()
```

I expect the output to be an artist and a string of letters on one line of the output then the title on the following row

> Here is the entire code: https://repl.it/@alexM99/Computer-Science-Coding-Project-Task-1-2

Comment: my full code is here: https://repl.it/@alexM99/Computer-Science-Coding-Project-Task-1-2

Comment: So you first pick an random artist, then a random song by the artist... and your sample just at this time only has one song for each but will have more?

Comment: Have all three columns returned by a single select.